# Append only numbers to a list from a mixed file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a txt file which looks like this:

```
    100.00   gasoline
    20.00    lunch
    12.50    cigarettes
```

I want to take only the numbers (100.00, 20.00, 12.50) and append them to a list, how can I do it? I tried with:

```
    tot_us = []
    for float in us_file:
        tot_us.append(float)
```

When I  print the list i get:

```
  ['100.00\tgasoline\n', '20.00\tlunch\n', '12.50\tcigarettes\n']
```

I was expecting:

```
  ['100.00', '20.00', '12.50']
```

I know is a noob attempt, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.split()` to break up each line into two sections:

```
total_us = []

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            bits = line.split('\t')
            total_us.append(bits[0])

print(total_us)
```

Or, you can use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    total_us = [row[0] for row in reader]

print(total_us)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I then used float(i) to convert them, append them to another list and do maths. I prefer method 1 since there's no need to import anything!

Answer (score 0):

You could also identify the position of the tab and then use slicing:

```
tot_us = []
for line in us_file:
    tab_pos = line.index('\t')
    float = line[:tab_pos]
    tot_us.append(float)
```

For more information about slicing see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/4681654).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this too, looks simpler!